# Do the ISS docking ports require maintenance?

Tags: iss, docking-port

Is it neccessary to maintain the docking ports of the ISS?

Inspection, cleaning, lubrication, replacement of worn out parts like O-ring seals?

Where are the seals, on both sides or only at the side of the docking space ships? If there are no O-rings at the ISS side, you don't need to replace them.

Comment: Not technically a duplicate, but some of the answers or related info are in this question:  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3373/how-many-docking-berthing-operations-can-a-cbm-port-tolerate

Answer (score 1):

According to this [schedual](https://blogs.nasa.gov/stationreport/2014/04/page/2/), the quest airlock does require maintenance.

"Airlock Cooling Loop Flush"

Not sure what an "Airlock Cooling Loop Flush" is but a google search reveals it has been done multiple times in the past.

Comment: Can you summarize the content, so this isn't a link-only answer?

Comment: Yup. One second let me edit it.

Comment: The airlock isn't a docking port.

Comment: Are they asking specifically about the docking adapters?